# XCode 5 and "merge into branch"

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5

I'm back working in XCode after a hiatus and just wanted to double check an apparent change in how XCode handles merging branches. It used to be (unless I completely understood) that to merge a branch into a master, one would switch to the master and then do a "merge from branch. This SO question seems to confirm that: [Using Xcode to merge current branch into Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129092/using-xcode-to-merge-current-branch-into-master)

Has this changed in XCode 5? There is now a a menu option in XCode 5 to "merge into branch" (and presumably stay in the current branh) which *seems* like it is no longer necessary to switch back to the master in order to merge a branch into it (for example, if one wants to keep working in the branch). I've looked over the [XCode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/MergingTwoBranches/MergingTwoBranches.html) but I don't want to screw up what I've done.

Have I got it right: "merge into branch" precludes the necessity of switching?

*(geez...I am long winded tonight. Sorry!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is still git: a merge is into the branch you are on.

> Have I got it right: "merge into branch" precludes the necessity of switching?

It doesn't preclude the necessity of switching; it just saves you a step by switching for you and then merging.

Comment: thanks - so if I am in Branch A and "merge into branch" master, I will end up in the master branch? (seems dumb and obvious but I messed up a couple of times before)